# How to get value of textbox in C# when it assign by jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am new to jQuery.

I have a web service which returns some data. I assign this data to a textbox using jQuery but when I want to access this value in C#, it generates an exception `incorrect format`.

This is my jquery code.

```
$('#Ltrl_GSalary').html(GrossSalary);
 $('#Ltrl_NetSalary').html(GrossSalary-parseInt(TotalDeduction));
```

This code works fine, it displays data.

I also tried:

```
$('#Ltrl_GSalary').val(GrossSalary);
 $('#Ltrl_NetSalary').val(GrossSalary-parseInt(TotalDeduction));
```

This code does not display any data.

This is my C# code

```
 salary.NetSalary = Ltrl_NetSalary.Text.ToDecimal();
 salary.GrossSalary = Ltrl_GSalary.Text.ToDecimal();
```

This causes the exception `incorrect format`.

Comment: looks like you `Ltrl_GSalary` is not an input element..since html() is working.. can you post your related html code

Comment: Ltrl_GSalary is asp.net lable control

Comment: Lable is not input type control, to get the values on server side code which change using jquery you need input type control like textbox, or you can use hidden field as well. Thanks

Comment: hidden field fields works thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Hidden field to capture data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ToInt32` for this purpose.

It will handle format exception. And check with value in `Ltrl_NetSalary.Text`

Try to use:

```
salary.NetSalary = Convert.ToInt32(Ltrl_NetSalary.Text);
salary.GrossSalary = Convert.ToInt32(Ltrl_GSalary.Text);
```

hope Its Helpful.